# Parsing Multipart/mixed in Spring

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-mvc, multipart

I want to parse requests like the following in my `RestController`

```
POST http://#.#.#.#:#/report HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Android
Accept: text/html,application/xml,application/json,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=%&REPORT_DIVIDER&%
Authorization: Basic ***
Content-Length: 23236
Host: #.#.#.#:#
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip


--%&REPORT_DIVIDER&%
Content-Type: application/json

{"content-excluded":true}
--%&REPORT_DIVIDER&%
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="INSTALLATION"

Content-Type: application/octet-stream
609903cf-fcc0-460c-87db-958e031ac156
--%&REPORT_DIVIDER&%--
```

This message is conform to [rfc1341](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html), yet I cannot find a way to parse this in Spring.

Note that the number of files may vary.

I've already tried using `CommonsMultipartResolver` or `StandardServletMultipartResolver`, but both only support `multipart/form-data` ([rfc1867](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1867.txt)).

Is there any way to parse these request in Spring besides writing my own parser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is not a very nice solution, it was the only one I found:

I essentially reimplemented `ServletFileUpload` with [this class](https://github.com/F43nd1r/acra-backend/tree/v0.5.0/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/fileupload/Rfc1341ServletFileUpload.java) and then loaded it into the apache library with [this simple subclass](https://github.com/F43nd1r/Acrarium/tree/v0.5.0/src/main/java/com/faendir/acra/rest/multipart/Rfc1341MultipartResolver.java) of `CommonsMultipartResolver`

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Path("api")
    @PUT
    @Consumes("multipart/mixed")
    @Produces("multipart/mixed")
    public MultiPart twelve( MultiPart multiPart) throws IOException {

    List<BodyPart> bodyParts = multiPart.getBodyParts();
    BodyPartEntity bpe = (BodyPartEntity) bodyParts.get(1).getEntity();
}
```

This is for jersey based spring boot project.